# SAS populate field from values in another dataset

Tags: sas

I know I have done this before and it shouldn't be difficult . . . but I am drawing a blank as to how to do this efficiently.

I have two tables:

**Table 1**

| primaryID | TypeID |
| --- | --- |
| 1001 | A |
| 1001 | B |
| 1001 | C |
| 1002 | B |
| 1003 | C |
| 1004 | A |
| 1004 | C |
| 1005 | B |

**Table 2**

| primaryID | valueA | valueB | valueC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 12 | 0.22 | 0.042 |
| 1002 | 10 | 0.19 | 0.039 |
| 1003 | 9 | 0.18 | 0.036 |
| 1004 | 14 | 0.3 | 0.062 |
| 1005 | 5 | 0.12 | 0.028 |

I want to create a new field (value) in table 1 from the value in table 2 that corresponds to TypeID from the row that matches primaryID

**Want**

| primaryID | TypeID | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | A | 12 |
| 1001 | B | 0.22 |
| 1001 | C | 0.042 |
| 1002 | B | 0.19 |
| 1003 | C | 0.036 |
| 1004 | A | 14 |
| 1004 | C | 0.062 |
| 1005 | B | 0.12 |

Thanks in advance

Comment: tanspose the second table and then merge or use proc sql to left join by primaryID and typeID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just fix table two so that it is in a useful form.

First let's convert your listings into actual data.

```
data table1 ;
  input primaryID $ TypeID $;
cards;
1001 A
1001 B
1001 C
1002 B
1003 C
1004 A
1004 C
1005 B
;

data table2;
  input primaryID $ valueA valueB valueC ;
cards;
1001 12 0.22 0.042
1002 10 0.19 0.039
1003  9 0.18 0.036
1004 14 0.3  0.062
1005  5 0.12 0.028
;
```

You could use PROC TRANSPOSE to convert those multiple variables into multiple observations.

```
proc transpose data=table2 out=tall;
  by primaryid;
  var value: ;
run;
```

Then use a simple data step to tease the type out of the name.

```
data tall ;
  set tall;
  length typeid $8;
  typeid = substr(_name_,6);
  rename col1=value;
run;
```

Now you can merge or join since the type is available to compare.

```
proc sql;
create table want as 
  select a.primaryid, a.typeid, b.value
  from table1 a left join tall b
  on a.primaryid = b.primaryid and a.typeid = b.typeid
  order by 1,2
;
quit;
```

If you don't mind losing some precision on the values by converting them into strings you could use the VVALUEX() function to do it with a single data step (assuming datasets are sorted).

```
data want;
  merge table1(in=in1) table2(in=in2);
  by primaryid;
  if in1;
  if in2 then value = input(vvaluex(cats('value',typeid)),32.);
  keep primaryid typeid value;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks! I was really over-complicating this for some reason. I think my brain may have started the weekend early . . .